# Collision - recognizing when object has stopped colliding

Tags: java, collision

What I mean is that when I collide with the side of an entity and want to jump, I cannot move right/left as I have a flag which prevents this when I collide with the entity on the right/left side, like so:

[image: img]

This is code code I use to detect collision:

```
public void onCollision(Wrapper wrapper) {
    if (horizontal_velocity == 0 && vertical_velocity == 0) {
        return;
    }

    Entity e1 = wrapper.thisEntity;  //the object we are controlling
    Entity e2 = wrapper.otherEntity; //the object we are impacting with

    Rectangle rect1 = wrapper.thisEntityRectangle;
    Rectangle rect2 = wrapper.otherEntityRectangle;

    int e1y = (int) rect1.getY(), e1x = (int) rect1.getX(), e1w = (int) rect1.getWidth(), e1h = (int) rect1.getHeight();
    int e2y = (int) rect2.getY(), e2x = (int) rect2.getX(), e2w = (int) rect2.getWidth(), e2h = (int) rect2.getHeight();

    e1x += e1w / 2;
    e1w /= 2;
    e1y += e1h / 2;
    e1h /= 2;


    //horizontal interaction -- x

    /*   ---+\\\\\\+---
     *      |------|
     *      |      |
     *  e1  |  e2  |  e1
     *      |      |
     *      |------|
     *   ---+\\\\\\+---
     */

    boolean touchingSide = false;

    if(e1y > e2y && e1y < e2y + e2h) {
        //touchingSide = true;
        if(e1x > e2x - e1w && e1x < e2x) { //going right || hitting left side
            collisionsHappening.put(wrapper.otherEntity.getID(), "right");
            canMoveRight = false;
            horizontal_velocity = 0;
            setX(e2x - e1w*2);
        }

        if(e1x < e2x + e2w + e1w && e1x > e2x) { //going left || hitting right side
            collisionsHappening.put(wrapper.otherEntity.getID(), "left");

            canMoveLeft = false;
            horizontal_velocity = 0;
            setX(e2x + e2w);
        }
    }

    //vertical interaction -- y

    /*
     *  \|     e1     |\
     *  \+--+------+--+\
     *  \\\\|      |\\\\
     *  \\\\|  e2  |\\\\
     *  \\\\|      |\\\\
     *  \+--+------+--+\
     *  \|     e1     |\
     *
     */

    if(e1x > e2x - e1w && e1x < e2x + e2w && !touchingSide) {
        if(e1y + e1h > e2y && e1y < e2y) { //going down || hitting top side
            collisionsHappening.put(wrapper.otherEntity.getID(), collisionsHappening.get(wrapper.otherEntity.getID()) + "|top");
            setY(e2y - e1h * 2);
            vertical_velocity = 0;
            //readyNextTurn = true;

            isFalling = false;
            onGround = true;
        }
        if(e1y - e1h < e2y + e2h && e1y > e2y) { //going up || hitting bottom side
            collisionsHappening.put(wrapper.otherEntity.getID(), collisionsHappening.get(wrapper.otherEntity.getID()) + "|bottom");
            setY(e2y + e2h + e1h);
            vertical_velocity = 0;
            //readyNextTurn = true;
            isFalling = false;
            onGround = true;

        }
    }
}
```

..and where the code is affected by the `canMoveRight` and `canMoveLeft` flags:

```
public void key(int keyCode) {
    try {
        onEdge();

        switch (keyList.get(keyCode)) {

            ...

            case MOVE_RIGHT:
                for(Entity e : objectsCollidingWith) {  //check if still colliding, if not, reset variable canMoveLeft inorder to not impair movement
                    if(collisionsHappening.get(e.getID()) == "right") {
                        canMoveRightNextFrame = true;
                    }
                }
                canMoveLeft = true;
                if (!canMoveRight && !canMoveRightNextFrame) break;

                if(canMoveRightNextFrame) {
                    canMoveRightNextFrame = false;
                    System.out.println(canMoveRightNextFrame);
                }

                if (horizontal_velocity == 0) {
                    horizontal_velocity = getXDisplacement();
                }
                changeX(horizontal_velocity);
                direction = "right";
                //horizontal_velocity = 0;
                break;
            case MOVE_LEFT:
                for(Entity e : objectsCollidingWith) {  //check if still colliding, if not, reset variable canMoveLeft inorder to not impair movement
                    if(collisionsHappening.get(e.getID()) == "left") {
                        canMoveLeftNextFrame = true;
                    }
                }
                canMoveRight = true;
                if (!canMoveLeft && !canMoveLeftNextFrame) {
                    break;
                }

                canMoveLeftNextFrame = canMoveLeftNextFrame ? true : false; //if true, make false

                if (horizontal_velocity == 0) {
                    horizontal_velocity = getXDisplacement();
                }
                changeX(-horizontal_velocity);
                direction = "left";
                //horizontal_velocity = 0;
                break;
            case JUMP:
                jump();
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        //ignore - a key with no action pressed
    }
}
```

---

## What I have tried

When I look for collisions - not react to them as shown in the above code - I tried to implement a HashMap in which I put a String - either `"left"` or `"right"` - to the key Entity.getID() which returns a unique name, like so (after the lines of code that are relevant are `// <<<`) :

```
public Wrapper[] collisions(Entity thisEntity) {
    ArrayList<Wrapper> wrappers = new ArrayList<Wrapper>();
    Player p = null;
    boolean isPlayer = thisEntity instanceof Player;
    boolean onGround = false;

    if (isPlayer) {
        p = (Player) thisEntity;
    }
    try {
        for (Entity e : getLevel().getEntities()) {
            if (!thisEntity.equals(e)) {
                collisionsHappening.put(e.getID(), "");  // <<<
                objectsCollidingWith.add(e);             // <<<
                if (thisEntity.getRect().intersects(e.getRect())) {
                    wrappers.add(new Wrapper(thisEntity, e, thisEntity.getRect(), e.getRect(),
                            thisEntity.getRect().intersection(e.getRect())));

                    onGround = true;
                    //collisionsHappening.put(e.getID(), true);
                    //System.out.println("collision between " + e.getID() + " + " + thisEntity.getID());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (isPlayer) {
        p.isTouching = onGround;
        if (onGround) {
            //System.out.println(onGround);
        }

    }
    //Entity[] result = list.toArray(new Entity[1]);
    return wrappers.toArray(new Wrapper[0]);
}
```

This system relies on keeping a flag 1 frame after the collision ceases in-order to remove the flags `canMoveRight` or `canMoveLeft` in the lines of code

```
for(Entity e : objectsCollidingWith) {  //check if still colliding, if not, reset variable canMoveLeft inorder to not impair movement
    if(collisionsHappening.get(e.getID()) == "left") {
        canMoveLeftNextFrame = true;
    }
    }
    canMoveRight = true;
    if (!canMoveLeft && !canMoveLeftNextFrame) {
        break;
    }

    if(canMoveLeftNextFrame) {
        canMoveLeftNextFrame = false; //if true, make false
    }

    ...
```

...and same for the `canMoveRight` flag...

---

However, this does not work, and I still cannot move mid-jump after I "scrape" the edge of an Entity unless I move in the opposite direction to "reset" the flag for the desired direction (line: `case MOVE_RIGHT:` `...` `canMoveLeft = true;` and `case MOVE_LEFT:` `...` `canMoveRight = true;`), as seen in the animation.

So, to conclude:

- How can I make this system work?
- Is there a more efficient/better way of doing this kind of thing?
- Do you recommend I redo my collision?

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend a reading on the Observer Pattern and how to implement it to detect colisions. Sorry, I'm too lazy now to make a proper answer. There are plenty material on this in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually impossible to approach this problem in such an event driven way for a game more advanced then Snake. I recommend that you focus on a simple update loop which updates each entity. Each entity then updates their own velocity and then position. Then check for collision and handle response. The key event handlers should not have any logic and be simply changing flags which the entities can poll.

As for the the collision and response part, that is where the meat of a simple platform game engine lies, and there are many different approaches. In the modern world of off the shelf physics engines, e.g. Box2D, you could simply let the physics system handle things. But from the sounds of things, you are not looking for that and what you want is what I call logic based physics.

If your world and entities consist of axis aligned boxes, you can separate horizontal and vertical motion into two discrete steps, for each entity. For each axis, each object tries to move as far as it can for (depending on velocity and collisions) if the object hits something, generate a collision event and set the velocity to zero on that axis. Repeat for the other axis and you will have a simple platform game engine. For this method you will need to handle the state of two objects touching carefully due to floating point numerical error. I recommend doing collision detection with integers (in the scale of the screen coordinates).

If you are looking to have an environment and entities which are not restricted to the axis aligned boxes, then you will have to get more complex and no longer rely on simply handling X then Y movement to give you things like a box sliding on the floor or down a wall. In this case I suggest you keep track of what surface your entity is standing or walking on so that you can handle their movement differently in each state. When they are in the air, normal movement, but when they are on some surface, the movement is constrained to horizontal movement and the vertical position is adjusted to keep them on the surface. You then will need to detect when they change states.

I hope you find this helpful. It turns out that it is not an easy topic to Google. (Update loops, collision detection, physics of motion, numerical integration and the geometry of collision response are all easy to Google). Most programmers seem to just take the approach of keep fiddling with it till it works, and so it never gets documented well.

P.S. Implicit Euler integration method is fine for most games.

Comment: Thanks! I looked up Implicit Euler integration and that's the method I am using at the moment, so glad to hear that it's OK, even though it is not as accurate over a large period of time which I just found out; should I be worried? Other wise I'll just research more about collision and read the book by Ericson...

Comment: I find that it is best to start with Implicit Euler integration. I personally have never run across a case in a platform jumping style simulation which has needed a more accurate method of integration. If I remember correctly, even a physics engine like Box2D uses it.